# How do I access a subclass's fields in RDLC?

Tags: .net, rdlc

I have a class named Orders that consists of three fields:
OrderID (int)
OrderDate (DateTime)
Details (List)

where Widget is a user-defined class that consists of:
WidgetID (int)
Name (string)
Quantity (int)

The code for the Orders class is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MySolution
{
    public class Orders
    {
        public int OrderID
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public DateTime OrderDate
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public List<Widget> Details
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public Orders()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

and the code for the Widget class is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MySolution
{
    [Serializable()]
    public class Widget
    {
        public int WidgetID
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public string Name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public int Quantity
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public Widget()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I create a Dataset in RDLC from a method in another class that returns a List,
using "Fields!Details.Value.WidgetID" does not work, even though Widget is Serializable.

Is there a way to access an Order row's Details' WidgetID values (e.g.) directly?

Does the fact that Details is a List have something to do with it? Do I need a subreport in a situation like this?

Comment: Do you want to create rdlc dynamically ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I "think" my problem has something to do with my Visual Studio install - ReportViewer.LocalReport.Render hangs whenever the report has a Dataset that includes a field that is a self-defined class, it loads (then unloads, then reloads) a number of DLLs, including System.Runtime.Serialization, and then hangs. There may be some mismatch between the VS DLLs and the version of the Microsoft.ReportViewer.* DLLs that I reference in the app.